# return type of overloading assignment operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why must the copy assignment operator return a reference/const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference)
>   [Operator= overloading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463437/operator-overloading-in-c)

I have already asked a question about this assignment operator overloading. I may be asking a foolish question. Pardon me.

My class declaration is like this:

```
class Circle
{
    public:
       Circle();
       Circle(const Circle &);
       Circle(unsigned short rad);
       unsigned short getRadius() const { return itsradius; }
       void setRadius(unsigned short rad) { itsRadius = rad; }
    private:
       unsigned short itsRadius:
};
```

My class definition:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
   itsRadius = 0;
}
Circle::Circle(unsigned short rad)
{
   itsRadius = rad;
}
Circle::Circle(const Circle & rhs)
{
   itsRadius = rhs.getRadius();
}
```

I am overloading assignment operator like this:

```
SimpleCircle & SimpleCircle::operator=(const SimpleCircle & rhs)
{
   itsRadius = rhs.getRadius();
   return *this;
}
```

When we are working on the current object like "itsRadius = rhs.getRadius()", the current object's radius will be changed, then, what is the need for returning "*this" ? Can this function be re-written as a void one ? Is there any problem with it ? Or is it just a standard to follow ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a good convention to follow to be consistent with the behavior of `operator=` for built-in types.

With built-in types you can do something like this:

```
int a, b, c;
// ...
a = b = c = 10;
```

If you do not return the reference to `*this`, the assignment chain won't be supported by your type.

Comment: And to cite Scott Meyers on the issue: "If in doubt, do it as the int's do" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Returning `*this` allows you to chain assignments like this,

```
SimpleCircle a, b, c(10);
a = b = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's convention, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29), and the [linked article by Richard Gillam](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html).

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to assign to multiple instances in one statement like this:

```
s1 = s2 = s3;
```