# use of class template requires argument list

Tags: c++, class, templates

So to start off, this is my vector class that I'm creating that basically functions like the standard library vector. We are now trying to make it a class template.

I've looked at a few examples of people struggling with this error, but I feel like the way I am declaring my function is just fine so I can't see the problem. Here are my declarations,

```
template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
public:
const MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);
...
}
```

The implementation code.

```
template <typename T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(const MyVector& b)
{
//set the vcapacity/vsize equal to the object passed to setup for a new deep copy
vcapacity = b.vcapacity;
vsize = b.vsize;

//allocate space for a new varray that is the copy
varray = new T[vcapacity];

//copy the data into the new array
for (int i = 0; i < vsize; i++)
{
    this->varray[i] = b.varray[i];
}
}
```

So I am basically getting the 2 errors which I assume are referring to the same thing. The first pointing to my first line of implementation after the template line saying "use of class template requires argument list", and the second pointing to the end of the implementation code stating, "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration".

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add both actual __complete__ error messages and the referred lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor parameter is missing the template parameter in the implementation:

```
template <typename T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(const MyVector<T>& b)
//                                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);
```

should be

```
MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);
```

[See Here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152978/return-type-of-overloading-assignment-operator-in-c)

For the errors, in the implementation use the template argument:

```
const MyVector<T>&
```

(By the way, were you aware you provided us the declaration of `operator=` and the implementation of the copy constructor?  :-) )

Anyway, think of it like this - in the implementation there is actually **no such class** as `MyVector`, there is **only** a class once a template argument is added.

Comment: Incorrect. `MyVector` in this context is the same thing as `MyVector<T>`.

Comment: Minimal counter example: `template <class T> struct vec{ const vec& operator=(const vec&){ return *this; } };`, compiles fine.

Comment: This is not entirely true. The line you have cited is valid. The error is elsewhere. The erroneous line should be modified as you suggest, but not this one.

Comment: I typed that out of habit, I always "say what I mean", but I actually meant to draw attention to dropping the const.  I'll update and explain why to drop const too.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first line of the implementation just after the last line of the template class definition and did you omit a `;` after the closing `}` of that definition as in the code you posted? A mistake commonly made (by me) that can cause error messages in the next included file when a header file ends with a class definition without ending `;`.