# How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, resize, move-semantics

I have a `std::vector` of objects of a certain class `A`. The class is non-trivial and has copy constructors *and* move constructors defined.

```
std::vector<A>  myvec;
```

If I fill-up the vector with `A` objects (using e.g. `myvec.push_back(a)`), the vector will grow in size, using the copy constructor `A( const A&)` to instantiate new copies of the elements in the vector.

Can I somehow enforce that the move constructor of class `A` is beging used instead?

Comment: You can, by using a move-aware vector implementation.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific how to achieve this?

Comment: You simply use a move-aware vector implementation. It sounds like your standard library implementation (which is it btw?) is not move-aware. You could try with move-aware containers from Boost.

Comment: Well, i I use gcc 4.5.1, which is move aware.

Comment: In my code it worked out to make the copy constructor private, even though the move constructor did not have the explicit "noexcept".

Answer (score 155):

You need to inform C++ (specifically `std::vector`) that your move constructor and destructor does not throw, using `noexcept`. Then the move constructor will be called when the vector grows.

This is how to declare and implement a move constuctor that is respected by `std::vector`:

```
A(A && rhs) noexcept { 
  std::cout << "i am the move constr" <<std::endl;
  ... some code doing the move ...  
  m_value=std::move(rhs.m_value) ; // etc...
}
```

If the constructor is not `noexcept`, `std::vector` can't use it, since then it can't ensure the exception guarantees demanded by the standard.

For more about what's said in the standard, read
[C++ Move semantics and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732084/c-move-semantics-and-exceptions)

Credit to Bo who hinted that it may have to do with exceptions. Also consider Kerrek SB's advice and use `emplace_back` when possible. It *can* be faster (but often is not), it can be clearer and more compact, but there are also some pitfalls (especially with non-explicit constructors).

**Edit**, often the default is what you want: move everything that can be moved, copy the rest. To explicitly ask for that, write

```
A(A && rhs) = default;
```

Doing that, you will get noexcept when possible: [Is the default Move constructor defined as noexcept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653726/is-the-default-move-constructor-defined-as-noexcept)

Note that early versions of Visual Studio 2015 and older did not support that, even though it supports move semantics.

Comment: Out of interest, how _does_ the impl "know" whether the `value_type`'s move ctor is `noexcept`? Perhaps the language restricts the function call candidate set when the calling scope is also a `noexcept` function?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assume it's just doing something such as http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible. There can be only one move constructor so it should be clearly defined by the declaration.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I've since learned that there is no (standard/useful) way to really know if there is a `noexcept` move constructor. `is_nothrow_move_constructible` will be true if there is a `nothrow` copy constructor. I'm not aware of any real case of expensive `nothrow` copy constructors so it's not clear that it really matters.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My destructor, move constructor, and move assigment functions are all marked `noexcept` in both header and implementation, and when I do a push_back(std:;move) it still calls the copy constructor. I am tearing my hair out here.

Comment: @alastairg please post a reproduce example for example at ideone. Perhaps you try to move from a const value or const reference? That gives you a copy.

Comment: @Johan I found the problem. I was using `std::move()` on the wrong `push_back()` call. One of those times when you are looking so hard for a problem that you don't see the obvious error right in front of you. And then it was lunchtime and I forgot to delete my comment.

Comment: But what if both the move ctor and the copy ctor can throw exceptions?

Comment: So, am I correct to assume `std::string` doesn't qualify as the destructor is not `noexcept`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/%7Ebasic_string. It's a real shame :(

Comment: Good questions, but destructors are (since many years) by default noexcept (under some rules). Check for "destructror" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec. I think the paper introducing this feature was https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3166.html back in 2010

Answer (score 19):

Interestingly, gcc 4.7.2's vector only uses move constructor if both the move constructor and the destructor are `noexcept`. A simple example:

```
struct foo {
    foo() {}
    foo( const foo & ) noexcept { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    foo( foo && ) noexcept { std::cout << "move\n"; }
    ~foo() noexcept {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector< foo > v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) v.emplace_back();
}
```

This outputs the expected:

```
move
move
move
```

However, when I remove `noexcept` from `~foo()`, the result is different:

```
copy
copy
copy
```

I guess this also answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127603/why-does-reallocating-a-vector-copy-instead-of-moving-the-elements).

Comment: It seems to me that the other answers only talk about the move constructor, not about the _destructor_ having to be noexcept.

Comment: Well, it should be, but as it turns out, in gcc 4.7.2 it wasn't. So this problem was, in fact, specific to gcc. It should be fixed in gcc 4.8.0, though. See [related stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721544/destructors-and-noexcept).

Answer (score -1):

It seems, that the only way (for C++17 and early), to enforce `std::vector` use move semantics on reallocation is deleting copy constructor :) . In this way it will use your move constructors or die trying, at compile time :).

There are many rules where `std::vector` MUST NOT use move constructor on reallocation, but nothing about where it **MUST USE** it.

```
template<class T>
class move_only : public T{
public:
   move_only(){}
   move_only(const move_only&) = delete;
   move_only(move_only&&) noexcept {};
   ~move_only() noexcept {};

   using T::T;   
};
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b110a17f66620ba4)

or

```
template<class T>
struct move_only{
   T value;

   template<class Arg, class ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<
            !std::is_same_v<move_only<T>&&, Arg >
            && !std::is_same_v<const move_only<T>&, Arg >
    >>
   move_only(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
      :value(std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
   {}

   move_only(){}
   move_only(const move_only&) = delete;   
   move_only(move_only&& other) noexcept : value(std::move(other.value)) {};    
   ~move_only() noexcept {};   
};
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71a13e7f652924d5)

Your `T` class must have `noexcept` move constructor/assigment operator and `noexcept` destructor. Otherwise you'll get compilation error.

```
std::vector<move_only<MyClass>> vec;
```

Comment: It is not necessary to delete copy constructor. If move constructor is noexcept, it will be used.

Comment: @balki It MAY be used. Standard does not REQUIRE this now. Here is discussion https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/std-proposals/j5URs5ZY3GI/AanXG977CAAJ