# Internal moving std::vector elements and QVector

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, stl, c++11

There are two vectors `std :: vector` and `QVector`. We have to check how "shift" elements when inserted. (Is constructed two vectors with the five elements and inserted zero element) I've this code:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QTextStream>

struct MoveTest
{
    int i;

    MoveTest()                       {}
    MoveTest(const MoveTest& other)  {QTextStream(stdout) << "constr copy" << endl;}
    MoveTest(MoveTest &&other)       {QTextStream(stdout) << "constr move" << endl;}
    ~MoveTest()                      {}

    inline MoveTest&    operator=   (const MoveTest& other) {QTextStream(stdout) << "copy" << endl;}
    inline MoveTest&    operator=   (MoveTest &&other)      {QTextStream(stdout) << "move" << endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "std::move:" << endl;
    MoveTest t1;
    MoveTest t2(std::move(t1));
    t1 = std::move(t2);

    QTextStream(stdout) << "QVector:" << endl;
    QVector<MoveTest> qmTest(5);
    qmTest.insert(qmTest.begin(), MoveTest());

    QTextStream(stdout) << "std::vector:" << endl;
    std::vector<MoveTest> mTest(5);
    mTest.insert(mTest.begin(), MoveTest());

    return 0;
}
```

My output with gcc 4.7.2, QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x:

```
std::move:
constr move
move
QVector:
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
std::vector:
constr move
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
constr copy
```

How to insert elements with an internal shift without copying? What GCC flags are needed?

Comment: a gift for you http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html ( yeah I'm getting emotional these days ... )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your move operator can throw an exception, `std::vector` can't use it. What would it do if the operator threw an exception halfway through the resize process? Declare it [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) if it cannot throw an exception and the the vector implementation can use it.

Comment: I'm added noexcept specifier, but out wasnt changed.

Comment: Because your class has a data member. As the rule says, "A declaration of a destructor that does not have an exception-specification is implicitly considered to have the same exception-specification as an implicit declaration."

Answer (score 1):

May be useful to someone.

```
struct MoveTest
{
    int i;

    MoveTest()                      {}
    MoveTest(MoveTest&&) noexcept   {std::cout << "constr move\n";}
    MoveTest(const MoveTest&)       {std::cout << "constr copy\n";}
    ~MoveTest() noexcept            {}

    MoveTest&   operator=   (MoveTest&&) noexcept   {std::cout << "move\n"; return *this;}
    MoveTest&   operator=   (const MoveTest&)       {std::cout << "copy\n"; return *this;}
};
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(MoveTest, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "std::move:\n";
    MoveTest t1;
    MoveTest t2(std::move(t1));
    MoveTest t3(std::move_if_noexcept(t2));
    t2 = std::move(t3);
    t1 = std::move_if_noexcept(t2);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "QVector:\n";
    QVector<MoveTest> qmTest(5);
    qmTest.insert(qmTest.begin(), MoveTest());
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "std::vector:\n";
    std::vector<MoveTest> mTest(5);
    mTest.insert(mTest.begin(), MoveTest());

    return 0;
}
```

Out:

```
std::move:
constr move
constr move
move
move

QVector:
constr copy
constr copy

std::vector:
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely containers in QT are capable of coping with move semantics. Run the example below and see for yourself.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>

struct MoveTest
{
    int i;

    MoveTest()                      {}
    MoveTest(MoveTest&&) noexcept   {std::cout << "constr move\n";}
    MoveTest(const MoveTest&)       {std::cout << "constr copy\n";}
    ~MoveTest() noexcept            {}

    MoveTest&   operator=   (MoveTest&&) noexcept   {std::cout << "move\n"; return *this;}
    MoveTest&   operator=   (const MoveTest&)       {std::cout << "copy\n"; return *this;}
};
Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(MoveTest, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "std::move:\n";
    MoveTest t1;
    MoveTest t2(std::move(t1));
    MoveTest t3(std::move_if_noexcept(t2));
    t2 = std::move(t3);
    t1 = std::move_if_noexcept(t2);
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "QVector:\n";
    QVector<MoveTest> qmTest;
    int i=5;
    while(i) {
        qmTest.append(MoveTest());
        --i;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "std::vector:\n";
    std::vector<MoveTest> mTest(5);
    mTest.insert(mTest.begin(), MoveTest());

    return 0;
}
```

Since two objects have similar use that doesn't mean that all member functions are the same. Check output below.
Out:

```
std::move:
constr move
constr move
move
move

QVector:
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move

std::vector:
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
constr move
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```