# GCC 4.8.1, C++11, shared libraries and exception handling trouble

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, shared-libraries, g++4.8

My project consists of the following:

- my program, written largely in C++11 (so it's not practical trying to compile it in C++03 mode)
- a shared library (https://github.com/SOCI/soci), compiled with the same compiler

SOCI throws exceptions I need to catch in my code. It used to work with GCC4.7.3, but now I've migrated to GCC4.8.1 it doesn't anymore: the exception falls through all handlers (including `catch(...)`) and causes termination:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'soci::mysql_soci_error'
  what():  Table 'brphrprhprh' doesn't exist
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

What I tried:

- throwing the same exception from my code (near the trouble point): it gets caught with the right handler;
- recompiling SOCI with `-std=c++11`: no difference
- adding `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to the exception class: no difference
- fiddling with the `-u` option for `typeinfo`-related symbols: no difference in behaviour, symbols appear as undefined in `nm` output. Note that without `-u`'s there are none at all:

  ```
  $ nm -D -C myprogram | grep soci | grep error
                   U soci::soci_error::soci_error(std::string const&)
  000000000044013a W soci::soci_error::~soci_error()
  0000000000440124 W soci::soci_error::~soci_error()
  0000000000440124 W soci::soci_error::~soci_error()
  00000000004c43b0 V typeinfo for soci::soci_error
                   U typeinfo for soci::mysql_soci_error
  00000000004c43d0 V typeinfo name for soci::soci_error
                   U typeinfo name for soci::mysql_soci_error
  00000000004c60c0 V vtable for soci::soci_error
                   U vtable for soci::mysql_soci_error
  ```

I also read http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility, but must be missing something else..

Any advice?

---

**EDIT**

Actually, that wasn't any dynamic library issue. *I should have immidiately tried to compile it statically* -- and save a lot of time because the behaviour wouldn't actually change. (See the answer)

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a minimal example?

Comment: @n.m. I'll try to. Though I'm unsure how "minimal" can it really be...

Comment: One main, one other function, one throw, one catch, one exception class, all split into a shared lib and an executable. Also, what nm -D shows on your shared lib?

Comment: Also, you have added the visibility attribute to the exception class, which implies you used to go without. This is certainly wrong. Perhaps you have added the attribute incorrectly?

Comment: @n.m. `nm -D soci_mysql.so` shows lotsa symbols, including the offending exception ctors, dtors, vtable and typeinfo. About visibility: the exception is defined in SOCI, I just stayed away from its sources while it was working for me :)

Comment: Are you loading the library with `dlopen`?

Comment: @n.m. No, just runtime linking. I'm currently stuck at reproducing the issue, example code either works as expected, or fails to link, so I try to mirror more and more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue... D'oh.

It was not that the exceptions were left uncaught! The call to `std::terminate` was made when the exception was being thrown out of a destructor, and that is not allowed by default in C++11. The actual issue I faced was this: [Destructors and noexcept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721544/destructors-and-noexcept) -- the compiler bug allowed me to stay unaware of the library bug...

Comment: FYI, SOCI bug has been fixed - https://github.com/SOCI/soci/pull/192 I'm sorry it hasn't happened earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I've forked it a while ago and discovered is's already there :)