# Will a vector of movable elements resize efficiently?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Let's assume `T` is moveable object:

```
vector<T> v;
v.resize(...)
```

if reallocation is needed, then will that code invoke copy, or move constructor on all elements?

If the answer is "move constructor" then how does the compiler know that it should use this one?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8001823/951890

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include<memory>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/dyF6JI

This code would not be compiled if `std::vector` used copy constructor.

> If the answer is "move constructor" then how does the compiler know that it should use this one?

`std::vector` could use `std::move`

If it use `std::move` but there's no move constructor, it will be equivalent to just using copy constructor

Comment: In order to meet the strong exception safety requirements, using `std::move_if_noexcept` is more likely.  This requires a noexcept move constructor unless the copy constructor is inaccessible, deleted, or otherwise unavailable.

Comment: If I remember right `vector` and the other standard containers actually use `move_if_noexcept` which is the same as a move if the move constructor is `noexcept` or a normal copy otherwise.

Comment: Darn. Beaten to the punch :-P