# std::vector and Move constructor

Tags: c++11, stl, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I want to use C++11 move semantics. And I wrote the following class:

```
class ColorM
{
public:
    ColorM(float _r, float _g, float _b, float _a){
        qDebug()<<"Constructor";
        r = _r;
        g = _g;
        b = _b;
        a = _a;

        m = new float[16];
    }


    ColorM(const ColorM &other){
        qDebug()<<"Copy Constructor";
    }


    ~ColorM(){
        if (m != nullptr)
        {
           qDebug()<<"Deleting resource.";
           // Delete the resource.
           delete[] m;
        }
    }

    // Move constructor.
    ColorM(ColorM&& other)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Move Constructor";
       r = other.r;
       g = other.g;
       b = other.b;
       a = other.a;
       m = other.m;


       other.m = nullptr;
    }


    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;

    float *m;
private:
};
```

When I try to:

```
std::vector<ColorM> vec;
vec.push_back(ColorM(0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));
vec.push_back(ColorM(0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));
vec.push_back(ColorM(0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));
```

I got copy constructor calls. What I doing wrong?
I have used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293665.aspx) as example. And compile it with g++.

Here is QT project I used for my tests: http://wikisend.com/download/261514/MoveConstructor.zip

Comment: Make the move constructor noexcept.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - And how noexcept helps? I have read your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows. Than I look at this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293665.aspx. And in MSDN version no noexcept.

Comment: @tower120: Think about the reallocation. Reallocation has to either succeed entirely, or not happen at all.

Comment: @Kerrek SB And what about MSDN version http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293665.aspx ?

Comment: @tower120: Ask the author?

Comment: @tower120 The article is about Visual Studio 2010, and in 2009-2010, some important changes happened to move constructors & exceptions; see [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2855.html) and [the solution](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html).

Comment: @DyP Will notice that. Though MSDN article a little bit outdated ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` function

```
std::vector<ColorM> vec;
vec.emplace_back(0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7);  // Will call 
vec.emplace_back(0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7);  //     ColorM::ColorM(float _r, float _g, ..) ctor
vec.emplace_back(0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7);
```

Or (use `ColorM` move constructor)

```
std::vector<ColorM> vec;
vec.emplace_back(ColorM(0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));  // Should be equivalent to your code
vec.emplace_back(ColorM(0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));
vec.emplace_back(ColorM(0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));
```

Note:  I disagree with the answer by `user2485710`.  Since the `ColorM(0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7)` argument to `push_back` is a temporary, I expect the compiler to recognize it as an r-value reference and apply the move constructor, *without* using `std::move`, since `push_back` [has an overload for r-value references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

In other words, the `emplace_back` taking a `ColorM` object should avoid copies like `push_back`; in the case of `emplace_back`, you will necessarily construct in place.

With the second version above, you should get better diagnostic messages compared to `push_back`, i.e. a failure at compile time instead of this subtle unexpected use of the copy constructor.

Comment: *"In other words, the emplace_back should behave the same as push_back"* Almost; `emplace_back` doesn't even need to move, it just constructs the value in-place.

Comment: Thanks, DyP, I will edit to clarify.  I was referring to `vec.emplace_back(ColorM(0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7));`, which will construct in place using the move constructor `ColorM(ColorM&& other)`

Comment: `emplace_back` uses `std::forward` **and** `std::move` to construct the object , that's not against what I said, those 2 are just 2 casting, the only difference is that 1 is unconditional where the other one is indeed conditional, and `emplace_back` does all this internally. Don't forget 1 thing: what can be an rvalue or a prvalue or whatever, is an _expression_ **not** an object, which means that you probably need the semantics before judging what is what.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the signatures for your constructors and the argument given to your `push_back()` operation.

In a nutshell `T()` generates a new instance of an object of type `T`, if this instance it's not related to a label/variable, the instance remains `unnamed`, but his doesn't change its own type, it's always "something" of type `T` ( it could be even considered as `T&` or `const T&` but that's not the argument of this topic).

To reach for the `T&&` signature you need to `cast` to `T&&` and in C++11 this is a job for [`std::move`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/) which is also an unconditional kind of cast, so it's quite easy to use pretty much anywhere.

You can add `std::move` to your constructor inside your class or inside the `push_back`, your call.

Comment: Please, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293665.aspx . Msdn says that it is enought just to v.push_back(MemoryBlock(25));

Comment: @tower120 they just choose to use the `std::move` cast **inside** the move constructor.

Comment: There is no word about exception at all! But I guess you're right.

Comment: @tower120 the main point is that `std::move` is a casting to `T&&`, once you are familiar with that, it's only a matter of design and where you consider more appropriate to use and implement this conversion.

Comment: Maybe, but I thought that MSDN article will teach me that :)

Comment: This is not correct. When you create a value via `T()`, this expression yields a prvalue. Prvalues, or, more generally rvalues, bind "stronger" to rvalue references than they do to lvalue references. `push_back` has two overloads; one taking a `const T&` (invoking a copy) and one taking a `T&&` (invoking a move). The latter is preferred for an rvalue argument expression.

Comment: @DyP what is not correct exactly ? can you show a way to obtain a `T&&` without using `std::move` at runtime or in the business logic of a C++11 application?

Comment: References are dropped from the type for expressions. Let's say we have two functions with signatures `void foo(ColorM const&)` (A) and `void foo(ColorM&&)` (B). Then, with `ColorM c(0,0,0,0);` we call 1) `foo(c);` 2) `foo(ColorM(0,0,0,0));` 3) `foo(std::move(c));`. The argument expression in 1) is an lvalue of type `ColorM`, so only (A) is viable. In 2), the argument expression is a prvalue of type `ColorM`, so (A) **and** (B) are viable; however, (B) is preferred. In 3), it is an xvalue (= rvalue *and* glvalue) of type `ColorM`, and overload resolution is the same as for 2).