# How do I make a vector reallocate with out calling a destructor?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, destructor

In this code:

```
Texture * a = new Texture();
Texture * b = new Texture();
buttons.push_back(*a);
buttons.push_back(*b);
```

`buttons` is a vector defined like this:

```
std::vector<Texture> buttons;
```

Texture is a class and this is its prototype:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Picture * texData;
    HitBox * texCoords;
    Texture();
    ~Texture();
    void render_tex();
};
```

The 4th line of the first code block is calling the destructor for Texture a. The problem is that this destructor deletes the values pointed to by `texData` and `texCoords` which means that when it is reallocated `texData` and `texCoords` point to junk data.

Is there a way to make it so that the vector will not call the destructor when it reallocates?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. It would work out much better to fix your class so it can be used with a vector, else not use it with a vector.

Comment: You need to define a `noexcept` move constructor for your `Texture` class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows.

Comment: Define a copy constructor and assignment operator too. Follow [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Why does the destructor delete `textData` and `texCoords`? Why are those pointers if the object owns the data, why not direct data members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bigger problem here. Since you have a destructor, you will also need to properly implement an assignment operator and copy constructor. Then your code will work fine as is. Google c++ and The Rule of Three. As mentioned, smart pointers could eliminate the need for the big three since they will handle copying and deleting for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're dynamically allocating the data members `texData` and `texCoords` you'll need to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator too, or your code will be very easily broken, as you've discovered.

But there's a better way! Do no use raw pointers as data members. Use `unique_ptr`s to hold them. (It's possible you don't need them to be pointers at all, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt here). You'll still need to define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, and manually copy the contents of what the `unique_ptr`s are holding, if you want the class to be copyable.

And to make it moveable you can explicitly `=default` both the move contructor and move assignment operators.

---

Also, your code is leaking memory. You allocate those objects dynamically, and then `push_back` a **copy** into the `vector`

```
Texture * a = new Texture();
buttons.push_back(*a);
```

You're dereferencing `a` and adding a *copy* of it to the `vector`. Unless you `delete a;` before it goes out of scope, you've got a memory leak. Use a `vector<unique_ptr<Texture>>` instead.

```
vector<unique_ptr<Texture>> buttons;

buttons.push_back(unique_ptr<Texture>(new Texture()));
```

With C++14 you can use `make_unique` to avoid having to `new` the object yourself

```
buttons.push_back(make_unique<Texture>());
```

Additionally, if you know the number of buttons you're going to add in advance you can `reserve` space to avoid reallocations.

```
buttons.reserve(num_buttons);
```

---

Now, chances are you do not actually need to dynamically allocate the `Texture` objects at all. All you probably need is

```
vector<Texture> buttons;
buttons.push_back(Texture());
```

If possible, I'd also define a move contructor and move assignment operator for `Texture` so that it can be moved when the vector reallocates, instead of being copied.

Comment: Good point, but your example isn't exception-safe.  (We need C++14 to hurry up so we can use `std::make_shared`)

Comment: @BenVoigt Getting there ... hold on :)

Comment: Thank you. The reason for the memory leak was I was trying to figure out what the problem was so this code is a little different from optimal. Additionally If I knew the number of buttons I could just use an array. I gave the answer check to Steger because his is more concise but thank you for the full answer

Comment: @0ctoDragon: Technically, Steger did not fully answer the question, though his observations are certainly valid.

Comment: @BenVoigt `std::make_shared` is already in C++11. C++14 will bring `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @Chnossos: Right you are.  And `make_unique` is what I meant ought to be used.

Comment: @BenVoigt And while we're picking away at your comment :) I don't agree with the exception unsafe part either. With or without `make_unique`, if either `new` or the `Texture()` constructor throws, `buttons` is left unchanged.

Comment: @Praetorian: Without `make_unique`, if reallocation of the vector fails (and throws) then isn't there a danger of leaking the `new Texture()` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt We're both wrong. The code I had wouldn't even have compiled because the `unique_ptr(T*)` constructor is `explicit`. Had I used `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` with my original example, you would be absolutely correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use *smart pointers* instead of *raw pointers*. The following listing uses `std::unique_ptr`. You can also use `std::shared_ptr`, if the object have several owners.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Texture>> buttons;

std::unique_ptr<Texture> a{new Texture()};
std::unique_ptr<Texture> b{new Texture()};
buttons.push_back(std::move(a));
buttons.push_back(std::move(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `Texture` own the `Picture` and `HitBox`? In which case, perhaps it should hold `Picture` and `HitBox` by value or `unique_ptr`. Aim for the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and don't have a destructor at all. Also, is there a good reason why you allocate `Texture` objects dynamically? I would suggest something like:

```
#include <vector>

struct Picture {};
struct HitBox {};

struct Texture {
  Picture texData;
  HitBox  texCoords;
  void renderTex() { }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Texture> textures(2);
}
```