# Vector pointers and passing objects by reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, reference

I have the following class:

```
class Database
{
private:
    vector<myObject*> m_vectorObj;

public: 
    void addObject(myObject &passObj)
}
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
void Database::addObject (myObject &passObj)
{
    m_vectorObj.push_back(passObj);
}
```

But is giving me the error "No matching function to call", how can I make this work and pass the object and store the pointer ?

Comment: `m_vectorObj.push_back(& passObj)`, but yeah it's better to change reference to pointer as Vlad suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ask yourself if you really need to use pointers

If you do, then you have 2 options.

## 1: You are just missing `&` before `passObj`

```
m_vectorObj.push_back(&passObj);
                      ^
```

## 2: Change your function (from reference to pointer)

```
void Database:addObject (myObject *passObj)//pointer to myObject instead of reference
{
    m_vectorObj.push_back(passObj);
}
```

---

I wouldn't use pointers at all, but i suggest you to encapsulate'em into [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Option 2 is better, +1 for option 2

Comment: you have to be careful with `std::unique_ptr`, as you cannot `push_back` it into the vector (it is not copy-constructible), but only `std::move`-it.

Comment: Thank you will apply option 2 :)

Comment: @IzonFreak Glad I helped you. BTW You should accept an answer

Comment: I gave you +1 now -1 for `unique_ptr`. Passing unique_ptr would mean that `passObj` changes owner, which may be not the case. When `m_vectorObj` will be destroyed wrapped `passObj` will be destroyed along with it.

Comment: @doc not really. When you use pointers, they will not be deleted when vector goes out of scope!

Comment: What you mean? If you pass object from one `unique_ptr` to another `unique_ptr` it changes owner.

Comment: @doc but not when you make unique when adding it into vector. Unfortunatelly it was only a suggestion, something that he can use to avoid memory leaks. As i said i wouldn't use pointers at all in this situations. In most cases, it is a sign of a bad programmer.

Comment: I think the opposite is true. Decent programmer can use pointers without memory leaks. `unique_ptr` is not a replacement of pointers. It's for different things. It's for sole ownership. For shared ownership you can use shared pointers or raw pointers. If method expects raw pointer then caller must guarantee that passed object will be alive for the time it is used within a callee. If this can't be guaranteed then you can use shared pointer, but it's last resort. And you can have subtle and hard to detect memory leaks with `shared_ptr` - worse than with raw pointers.

Comment: @I didn't say that smart pointers are a replacement of pointers. I said that most programmers are using pointers everywhere, even if there is no need for pointer

Comment: @vsoftco are they even usable within vector, which copies its elements during resize for example?

Comment: @doc, good point, forgot about the resize. If your move ctor and destructor are declared as `noexcept`, then the move ctor will be used during resizing. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8001823/3093378

Comment: @doc it s usable. When you declared your move constructor as noexcept, std::vector will use move instead. And for your comments above, when you std::move unique_ptr into a vector, it will not.change ownership

Comment: @Quest As I read from another question, some functions for `std::vector` are still unusable, so IMO it's not the best idea to use `std::unique_ptr` with `std::vector`. If you move `unique_ptr` to `vector` it changes ownership, why shouldn't it? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7bfd379825f715b

Comment: @doc I was thinking about passing a pointer into a function and directly pass newly created unique_ptr into the vector

Comment: @Quest this does not make any difference, because newly created `unique_ptr` will take ownership of pointer -> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/869fd0c892adca93 Using `unique_ptr` in such way does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

you are passing a reference to a pointer type, which does not equal any prototype call you have.

If you want to add pointers change your code to accept pointer objects:

```
void Database::addObject (myObject * passObj)
{
   m_vectorObj.push_back(passObj);
}

//somewhere:
Database db;
db.addObject(new myObject);
```

note that references are usually ment for modyfiing the passed arguments

Answer (score 0):

Scope resolution operator is '::' not ':'. Change void DataBase:addObject to DataBase::addObject.