# Lambda as an argument to std::vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I came across code that passes a lambda as an argument to emplace_back, which confused me. So I wrote a small test to validate the syntax like this:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){cout<<"constructed"<<endl;}
    A(const A& other){a = other.a; cout<<"copied"<<endl;}
    A(const A&& other){a = other.a; cout<<"moved"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
   vector<A> vec;
   vec.emplace_back(
       []{A a;
       a.a = 1;
       return a;   
       }());

   A a2;
   a2.a = 2;
   vec.emplace_back(std::move(a2));

  return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:
1) Can someone clarify how a lambda can be passed as an argument to emplace_back? I had only seen constructor arguments being passed to emplace back in the past. 
2) The output was:

```
constructed
moved
constructed
moved
copied
```

Where is the last copied coming from? Why aren't the two approaches equivalent.

Comment: It's the result of the lambda that's being emplaced. Notice the extra `()` in `}());` at the end of the lambda. The lambda is evaluated immediately.

Comment: True, but does that mean that I can call any function in emplace_back, as long as the return can be passed to the constructor?

Comment: Yes. When arguments are evaluated, if the expression is a function call, that function's result will be used. This is how all functions work, not just `emplace_back`. Be sure to understand that `emplace_back` never sees the function. It only ever sees the result.

Comment: Consider reading a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone clarify how a lambda can be passed as an argument to emplace_back?

You are not passing a lambda. Instead, you pass the **result** of calling the lambda.

> Where is the last copied coming from?

It comes from the vector. When `a2` is inserted to `vec`, a reallocation occurs, which reallocates memory and **copy** the objects in the old memory to the new memory.

If you specify the move constructor as `noexcept`, i.e.

```
A(const A&& other) noexcept {a = other.a; cout<<"moved"<<endl;}
```

then `std::vector` will move the objects during reallocation instead of copying, and you can see the last copy becomes move.

Comment: Thanks for the insight about the realloc. That was it. However, the noexcept did not change the behavior. I marked the copy constructor as = delete in order to get the 'copied' to become 'moved'. Why would you expect noexcept to change that?

Comment: @Haytham See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864895/5376789). Do you use VS2015 or older?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `()` after the lambda definition, which calls the lambda. This code is equivalent to the following:

```
int main()
{
    auto make_a = []()
    {
        A a;
        a.a = 1;
        return a;
    };

    vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(make_a());

    // ...
}
```

Which, since the lambda has empty capture, is equivalent to this:

```
A make_a()
{
    A a;
    a.a = 1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(make_a());

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's helpful.