# Copy constructor being preferred over move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a simple JSON parser for fun, and I've got my value type:

```
typedef enum {
    JSON_NULL,
    JSON_NUMBER,
    JSON_STRING,
    JSON_ARRAY,
    JSON_OBJECT,
    JSON_BOOLEAN
} json_type_t;

// datatype for json value
struct json_value {
    using arr_type = vector<json_value>;
    using obj_pair = pair<string, json_value>;
    using obj_type = unordered_map<string, json_value>;

    // constructors 
    json_value()
        : type(JSON_NULL) {}

    json_value(json_type_t type)
        : type(type) {
        switch(type) {
            case JSON_STRING:  str = new string;   break;
            case JSON_ARRAY:   arr = new arr_type; break;
            case JSON_OBJECT:  obj = new obj_type; break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // copy construct
    json_value(const json_value& other) {
        printf("copying json value\n");
        if (other.type != JSON_NULL) {
            type = other.type;
            switch(type) {
                case JSON_NULL:                                    return;
                case JSON_NUMBER:  num = other.num;                return;
                case JSON_BOOLEAN: val = other.val;                return;         
                case JSON_STRING:  str = new string  (*other.str); return;
                case JSON_ARRAY:   arr = new arr_type(*other.arr); return;
                case JSON_OBJECT:  obj = new obj_type(*other.obj); return;
            }
        }
    }

    // move construct
    json_value(json_value&& other) {
        type = other.type;
        switch(type) {
            case JSON_NULL:                     break;
            case JSON_NUMBER:  num = other.num; break;
            case JSON_BOOLEAN: val = other.val; break; 
            case JSON_STRING:  str = other.str; other.str = nullptr; break;
            case JSON_ARRAY:   arr = other.arr; other.arr = nullptr; break;
            case JSON_OBJECT:  obj = other.obj; other.obj = nullptr; break;
        }
    }

    // assignment operator copy/swap idiom
    json_value& operator =(json_value other) {
        destroy();
        type = other.type;
        switch(type) {
            case JSON_NULL:                     break;
            case JSON_NUMBER:  num = other.num; break;
            case JSON_BOOLEAN: val = other.val; break; 
            case JSON_STRING:  str = other.str; other.str = nullptr; break;
            case JSON_ARRAY:   arr = other.arr; other.arr = nullptr; break;
            case JSON_OBJECT:  obj = other.obj; other.obj = nullptr; break;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // destructor
    ~json_value() {
        destroy();
    }

    // type of value and union to hold data
    json_type_t type = JSON_NULL;
    union { 
        bool      val;
        double    num;
        string   *str;
        arr_type *arr;
        obj_type *obj;
    };

private:
    // cleanup our memory
    void destroy() { 
        switch(type) {
            case JSON_NULL:    break;
            case JSON_NUMBER:  break;
            case JSON_BOOLEAN: break; 
            case JSON_STRING:  delete str; break;
            case JSON_ARRAY:   delete arr; break;
            case JSON_OBJECT:  delete obj; break;
        }
        type = JSON_NULL;
    }
};
```

I've written proper copy/move constructors and an assignment operator.  My issue is that, when running a particular benchmark, the parser takes about 40ms.  Trying to optimize a bit, I commented out the copy constructor to make sure I'm not making any unecessary copies.  Sure enough, my code still compiles, indicating the move constructor is sufficient,  *and* it's ~25% faster!

Instrumenting the copy constructor, I can see it is indeed being called, but as I've shown, the move constructor is sufficient.

So, my question is, in what contexts would a copy constructor be preferred over the move constructor, and how can I find where that's happening?

Comment: Do you, by chance, ever use `json_value` inside a standard container?

Comment: @Justin indeed, see the first three `using`s at the top of `json_value`

Comment: I use std::pair, std::vector and std::unordered_map as a keypair, json_array and json_object respectively.  They're part of json_value, and recursively hold json_values.

Comment: Unrelated: A move assignment operator might be a good addition.

Comment: You likely just need to make your move constructor and move assignment operator `noexcept`. For exception safety, if you don't, containers will prefer the copy constructor.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows) might be your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard containers all try to have the [*strong exception guarantee*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety), meaning that if an exception is thrown, it's as if nothing happened.

Take the case of `std::vector`. In order to keep this guarantee, it can only use the move constructor if it's guaranteed that moving won't throw. Consider the case when the vector needs to resize its buffer:

```
d // new element to push_back
[a][b][c] // old, filled buffer
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] // new, empty buffer
```

Moving the new element in place isn't a problem, even if it throws, since we'll still have the old buffer that we can use:

```
[a][b][c]
[ ][ ][ ][d][ ][ ]
```

But when we move the old buffer's elements into the new buffer, what happens if we throw in the middle?

```
[ ][#][c]
[a][#][ ][d][ ][ ]
```

We don't know the state that `b` is in when it throws, so how do we recreate the old state? Even if we were able to resurrect `b`, we can't just go and move the prior elements back, because moving those could throw too.

If we fall back on a copy, we could back out at any time by just discarding the new buffer.

Thus, in order to keep the *strong exception guarantee*, `std::vector` can't move unless the move constructor is `noexcept`.

---

Declaring the move operations as `noexcept` is necessary for the standard containers to use them. Most of the time, move constructors and move assignments can be `noexcept`, so declare them as such when they are:

```
json_value(json_value&& other) noexcept {
    // ...
}

json_value& operator=(json_value&& other) noexcept {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And indeed it does!

Comment: Nitpick : If you don't have a copy constructor, the throwing move constructor will be used. So it's not impossible to use the move constructor. `std::vector` can use a throwing move constructor but will only do so if there's no choice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed, in that case, you lose the *strong exception guarantee*.