# Why does code with std::vector not compile but with std::unique_ptr it does, if there is no noexcept move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

Why can the following program not be compiled?

NB: something_t's move constructor is not noexcept.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class something_t {
public:
    constexpr something_t() = default;

    constexpr something_t(const something_t& other)
        : field_(other.field_) {
    }

    constexpr something_t(something_t&& other)
        : field_(other.field_) {
    }

private:
    unsigned int field_{ 0 };
};

struct data_t {
    something_t something;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> move_only; // <-- this line
};

int main() {
    std::vector<data_t> result;
    data_t data;
    result.push_back(std::move(data));
    return 0;
}
```

Error is (within g++):

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:127:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
127 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
    |                                                                        ^~~~~
```

(nearly the same with clang and MSVC).

If I replace the line with the "this line" comment by `std::unique_ptr<int> move_only` then the code compiles fine:

```
    struct data_t {
        something_t something;
        std::unique_ptr<int> move_only;
    };
```

Why does removing `std::vector` help? It also compiles with or without `std::vector` if I make the `something_t` move constructor noexcept.

NB: adding `noexcept` to `something_t`'s move constructor helps, but that's not the question.

Question is:

Why with this:

```
    struct data_t {
        something_t something;
        std::unique_ptr<int> move_only;
    };
```

does the program compile?

But with

```
struct data_t {
    something_t something;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> move_only; // <-- this line
};
```

does the program NOT compile?

In fact, both `std::unique_ptr<int>` and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`:

- non-copyable
- noexcept-moveable

So they have the same properties.

Update: I've tried to compare the type_traits of both variants:

```
                                                data_t(vector)          data_t(unique_ptr):
is_constructible:                               true                    true
is_trivially_constructible:                     false                   false
is_nothrow_constructible:                       true                    true
is_default_constructible:                       true                    true
is_trivially_default_constructible:             false                   false
is_nothrow_default_constructible:               true                    true
is_copy_constructible:                          true                    false
is_trivially_copy_constructible:                false                   false
is_nothrow_copy_constructible:                  false                   false
is_move_constructible:                          true                    true
is_trivially_move_constructible:                false                   false
is_nothrow_move_constructible:                  false                   false
is_assignable:                                  false                   false
is_trivially_assignable:                        false                   false
is_nothrow_assignable:                          false                   false
is_copy_assignable:                             false                   false
is_trivially_copy_assignable:                   false                   false
is_nothrow_copy_assignable:                     false                   false
is_move_assignable:                             false                   false
is_trivially_move_assignable:                   false                   false
is_nothrow_move_assignable:                     false                   false
is_destructible:                                true                    true
is_trivially_destructible:                      false                   false
is_nothrow_destructible:                        true                    true
is_swappable:                                   false                   false
is_nothrow_swappable:                           false                   false
```

The only difference is:

```
is_copy_constructible:                          true                    false
```

I.e., `data_t` with `vector` is copy-constructible, and with `unique_ptr` it is not. But how can this difference affect compilation?

Comment: it seems your question is really why the code without `move_only` CAN be compiled?  The problem with unique_ptr has been answered several times the last couple of days

Comment: my question is: why with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` it cannot be compiled, but with `std::unique_ptr<int>` it CAN be compiled?

Comment: @M.M The question is, why this code with `std::unique_ptr<int> move_only;` does compile. It seems `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` has the same properties as `std::unique_ptr<int>` where it matters (namely, both are not copyable, and both are noexcept-movable). I, for one, am baffled that replacing one with the other makes a difference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes

Comment: Are you saying that adding `noexcept` to `something_t` move ctor makes it compile with and without `std::vector`?

Comment: @Slava Yes, after adding noexcept the program compiles successfully.

Comment: @Slava Yes, but [that's easy to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows). That's not the surprising part.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Probably, it is just not clear from OP's explanation. If you clearly understand what OP means you probably should correct the question, it is quite cryptic even for me.

Comment: @Slava I've tried to clarify my question, please take a look.

Comment: Its ok, just this "There is the same problem with absence with noexcept, isn't it?" is very confusing. I can try to fix it but English is not my first language either. Btw what NB means?

Comment: NB == nota bene == take a look

Comment: I tried to fix it as much as I can, if you do not mind

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I read the link, looks like they are doing their best to kill the language. Quite soon it will be impossible to understand what is going on. I could only imagine how difficult to novice programmer to write correct and efficient programs.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @Slava I've tried to compare type_traits for both variants of `data_t`, the only difference is that `data_t` with `vector` is copy constructible, and with `unique_ptr` it is not. I've updated the question with comparison table. But I still cannot understand how this affects compilation.

Comment: Asked another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110834/why-is-copy-constructible-vvectorunique-ptrint-is-true-but-it-cannot-be-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important difference here is:

```
std::is_copy_constructible<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>>::value == true
std::is_copy_constructible<std::unique_ptr<int>>::value == false
```

That first one is maybe surprising. But note that `is_copy_constructible` and most similar type traits only require that the operation they test is declared, not that it would be valid to actually use. `std::vector` unfortunately lacks some "SFINAE correctness" here, but that might be intentional for backwards compatibility.

The Standard's description of `template <class T, class Allocator> class vector` in [[vector.overview]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector#overview-2) simply says that it declares a member `vector(const vector& x);`. The following sections say nothing else about the copy constructor. In particular, `std::vector` doesn't have a piece similar to this sentence from [[optional.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional.ctor#6) about the copy constructor of `std::optional<T>`:

> ```
> constexpr optional(const optional& rhs);
> ```
>
> *Remarks:* This constructor shall be defined as deleted unless `is_­copy_­constructible_­v<T>` is true.

Because of the various requirements on `std::vector<T>`, its functions like `push_back`, `insert`, and `emplace` which need to deal with the possibility of reallocating and populating new memory with elements already in the vector are forced to be implemented like this:

- If `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is true, uses the move constructor of `T`, and the functions provide the strong exception guarantee.
- If `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is false and `std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value` is true, uses the copy constructor of `T`, and the functions provide the strong exception guarantee.
- If `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` and `std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value` are both false, uses the move constructor of `T`, but the functions cannot provide the strong exception guarantee.

(`T` must be move constructible, which might actually mean using a copy constructor, as a general requirement of these container functions.)

So when `data_t` has a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` member, it "incorrectly" has an implicitly declared copy constructor which is not deleted. This leads to `std::vector<data_t>::push_back` choosing the second option from the list above, but the actual use of the copy constructor leads to errors.

When `data_t` has a `std::unique_ptr<int>` member, its deleted copy constructor means that the implicitly declared copy constructor of `data_t` is also deleted. So in this case, `std::vector<data_t>::push_back` chooses the third option from the list above, using the move constructor, but if it does throw, the vector is left in an unspecified state.

Comment: Thanks! So, is this a bug in STL (or Standard)?

Comment: Bug, oversight, or backwards-compatibility feature. Thankfully the issue can be resolved by explicitly deleting the `data_t` copy constructor and copy-assignment operators.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/pgWYGIvV2Tw/8OteiWGUXfwJ . Some suggested there that many things like this might be changed once concepts are in the language. Though I don't know if the committee would go for that, since it could change meaning of existing code. And the C++2a draft has concepts, but has not changed the vector copy constructor or other such things.