# Why is_copy_constructible_v<vector<unique_ptr<int>>> is true, but it cannot be copied?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

```
using T = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>;
```

Why `std::is_copy_constructible<T>` is `true`, but following does not compile:

```
using T = vector<unique_ptr<int>>;

T v1;
T v2 = v1;
```

(It does not compile in Clang, GCC and MSVC with C++17.)

Comment: Good question, this particular case was asked before. Basically, is_copy_constructible cannot "see" past the existence of the copy constructor that would ultimately fail when invoked.

Comment: @GManNickG see also interesting bug causes by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110426/why-code-with-stdvector-fails-to-compile-but-with-stdunique-ptr-does-not-if