# Why adding a defaulted move assignment operator breaks compilation of standard swap function?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, raii

In the following code, if move assignment is uncommented the swap function stops compilation of the program. I observed this behavior on all 3 major compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC).

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

struct test
{
    test() = default;

    test(test&& other) noexcept = default;
    //test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept = default;

    test(const test& other)
    : ptr(std::make_unique<int>(*other.ptr))
    {}

    test& operator=(test other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};
```

Godbolt test: https://godbolt.org/z/v1hGzzEaz

Looking into standard library implementations, they use SFINAE or concepts to enable/disable `std::swap` overloads and when the special function is uncommented, for some reason, some traits are failing (`is_move_constructible` and/or `is_move_assignable` on libstdc++).

My question is: why adding a defaulted special member function prevents the standard library from viewing the type as moveable?

Edit 1: turns out the problem is that xvalues have no preference in overload resolution between `T` and `T&&` (which causes ambiguous overload error) so standard library traits fail to recognize the type as moveable.

Edit 2: important: note that the example code IS NOT a proper implementation of the copy and swap idiom. It should be done with custom swap function or use all 5 special member functions. The current implementation creates infinite recursion of move/copy assignment and swap calls.

Comment: Did you typo `test& operator=(test other)` to take `other` by value instead of by const reference in the actual code as well?

Comment: I'm tempted to close as a typo. `std::swap(*this, other);` is implemented in terms of move-ctor and move-assignment, you get an infinite recursion here. It should be `std::swap(ptr, other.ptr);`.

Comment: @Botje No, this is the copy&swap idiom. Taking by value is intentional, and has some benefits.

Comment: Side note: copy&swap `operator=` should be `noexcept`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat added missing `noexcept`, nothing has changed in regards to compilation problem.

Comment: `noexcept` isn't what causes the problem, that's why I said "side note". The missing `noexcept` just [causes unnecessary copies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8001823/2752075) when the class is used as an element of `std::vector` and probably some other containers. Your problem is caused by passing the wrong thing to `std::swap`, see my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly. In addition to what I said: you don't need both `operator=(test)` and `operator=(const test &)`, the former replaces both the latter and `operator(test &&)` (if you have the copy and move constructors respectively). If you want to provide a custom move assignment, then it should be accompanied by `operator=(const test &)`, not `operator=(test)`.

Comment: In the future, I suggest posting the broken code directly in the question, without us needing to comment/uncomment some parts. Not sure about others, but I tend to read the code first, disregarding most text around it. :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True, I don't need both assignment operators. The correct way of implementing copy and swap here is to have only 4 special member functions. But adding move assignment shouldn't break standard library.

Regrding the post and your reading habits - sorry, this is your problem. You are supposed to read the text around it. And from practical point of view, it's much better to write "uncomment this line to break" than the reverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main implementation of `std::swap` uses move assignment internally and looks something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
  requires std::is_swappable_v<T> // exposition-only, constraint might be different
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T c = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(c);
}
```

This means that move assignment needs to be valid for your type, but it isn't.
If you were to call the move assignment operator, you would get an error:

```cpp
<source>:18:15: error: use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous [...]
[...] |
<source>:9:11: note: candidate function
    9 |     test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept = default;
      |           ^
<source>:15:11: note: candidate function
   15 |     test& operator=(test other);
      |           ^
```

[`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is constrained so that only [*MoveAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) types can be swapped, and yours can't be.
Both `=` operators can be called with an xvalue, and neither is a better match.
This is due to the fact that only lvalue-to-rvalue conversion lenghtens the conversion sequence, and initializing an object from an xvalue is considered "free" (as in, this isn't a conversion and not any worse than binding a reference).

Even if you could call `std::swap`, you cannot simultaneously

- rely on `std::swap`'s default implementation which uses `operator=`
- define `operator=` in terms of `std::swap`

This would be infinite recursion as the definition of `=` and `std::swap` is circular.

#### Solutions

You can define a custom `swap` for your type so that you no longer rely on `std::swap`.
Only keep `operator=(test)`, which would look like:

```cpp
friend void swap(test& a, test& b) noexcept {
    using std::swap;    // Use swap() functions found through ADL, fall back
    swap(a.ptr, b.ptr); // onto std::swap if there are none.
}                       // (not necessary if you only have a std::unique_ptr member,
                        // you could just use std::swap(a.ptr, b.ptr)).

test& operator=(test other) noexcept {
    swap(*this, other); // custom function, not std::swap
    return *this;
}
```

You can also define separate `operator=(const test&)` and `operator=(test&&)` manually, so that `std::swap` would use the move assignment operator and there would be no ambiguity in overload resolution.

Comment: "Both operators can be called with an xvalue, and neither is a better match." This is surprising. I expected lvalue to land into const lvalue reference overload and both rvalues (prvalue and xvalue) to land into rvalue reference overload.

Comment: @Xeverous But you don't have an rvalue reference overload.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I do when the overload is uncommented. Then the code breaks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read today, apparently. No `const T &` overload, I mean. Only `T` and `T &&`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed. Still a surprise for me that xvalues have no preference.

Comment: "You can also define separate [...]" actually I have to because the current implementation creates an infiite recursion of swap and move assignment calls.

Comment: @Xeverous personally I would still implement a custom `swap` operation for the type. Custom `swap`s are generally useful and can have quite a significant performance impact, and if you're defining it yourself anyway, then you can delegate `operator=` to it with no recursion. Defining separate, fully manual copy/move assignment operators is really just a micro-optimization in most cases.

Comment: The problem arose in production code but not from optimization goals but to be able to copy a class which stored unique pointers (the stored objects have a virtual clone method) - thus the custom copy ctor was needed. Then I encountered surprising compilation error.