# is there any reason to use non noexcept Move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, noexcept

Is there any practical reason to use **NON NOEXCEPT** move constructor  in c++11 ?

Because, `std::vector` uses move constructor if it's declared as `noexcep`, but I can't imagine any practical using non-noexcept move constructor.

Comment: One of the changes to in the standardization process for C++11 was to allow throwing move-constructors. An example of a throwing move constructor is an aggregate, where one member can only be copied, and that copy-ctor can throw. I think this one is the proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4732084/420683