# vector<map<move-only type>> does not compile with MSVC

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, move-semantics

Making a vector of a map of move-only types doesn't seem to work properly on Windows.
See code here: https://godbolt.org/z/yAHmzh

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

// vector<vector<move-only>> works
void foo() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> outer;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> inner;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    inner.push_back(std::move(p));
    outer.push_back(std::move(inner));
}

// vector<map<move-only>> fails to compile upon inserting an element.
void bar() {
    std::vector<std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>>> vec;
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>> map;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_unique<int>(2);

    map.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(p1), std::move(p2)));

    // The following line fails to compile on windows. It errors with a message about
    // the unique_ptr copy constructor being explicitly deleted. This seems to only happen
    // on windows. GCC and clang have no problem with this.
    vec.push_back(std::move(map));
}

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    foo();

    bar();
}
```

GCC and Clang have no problem with that code, but MSVC fails to compile.

Looking for a workaround to let me do this that will compile on all major compilers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enforce [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) for vector, we need to inform C++ (specifically [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) that the move constructor and destructor does not throw, using `noexcept`. Then the [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) will be called when the vector grows. See this note:

> To make the strong exception guarantee possible, user-defined move constructors should not throw exceptions. For example, std::vector relies on std::move_if_noexcept to choose between move and copy when the elements need to be relocated.

For more about what's said in the standard, read 
[C++ Move semantics and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732084/c-move-semantics-and-exceptions)

If the constructor is not [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), *std::vector* can't use it, since then it can't ensure the exception guarantees demanded by the standard.

In case of [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), the standard doesn't say anything about exception safety for move constructor of the map. So, compilers (in your case, `gcc` and `clang`) can mark functions as noexcept irrelevant of whether the Standard mandates it or not.

For alternatives or workaround, see my example below (tested with `gcc`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

void foo(void) 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> outer;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> inner;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    inner.emplace_back(std::move(p));
    outer.emplace_back(std::move(inner));
}

void bar(void) 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>>> vec;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_unique<int>(2);

    auto pair = std::make_pair(std::move(p1), std::move(p2));

    vec.emplace_back(std::move(pair));
}

void bar2(void) 
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>>>> vec;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = std::make_unique<int>(2);

    auto map = std::make_unique<std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>>>();
    map->emplace(std::move(p1), std::move(p2));

    vec.emplace_back(std::move(map));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

**BONUS:**

Use [emplace_back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306581/5735010) when possible. It *can* be faster (but often is not), it can be clearer and more compact, but there are also some pitfalls (especially with non-explicit constructors).

Comment: "If the constructor is not noexcept, std::vector can't use it" - that's not true in all cases; it will use it, even though it's not `noexcept`, if it can't use the copy constructor at all (hint ;-) ).

Comment: vector<unique_ptr<map<move-only>>> is a good workaround, thanks!

Comment: *"the standard doesn't say anything about exception safety for [..]. So, compilers [..] can mark functions as `noexcept`"* See [res.on.exception.handling-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#res.on.exception.handling-5). Notice that it is not true for `constexpr` ([constexpr.functions-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#constexpr.functions-1)).

Answer (score 4):

The move constructor of `std::map` is not defined to be `noexcept` by the Standard. Therefore `std::vector` falls back to using the copy constructor (e.g. by the use of `std::move_if_noexcept`).

That said, compilers are allowed to mark functions as `noexcept` irrelevant of whether the Standard mandates it or not. This is probably what GCC and Clang do (the libraries that they use).

You'll notice the same situation applies for `std::vector<std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>>` (and perhaps other).

Comment: Yep, I understand the problem, was just wondering if there's a workaround.